# Screen brightness randomly set to lowest setting Lenovo ThinkCenter

Tags: display, external-display, brightness, thinkcentre

On multiple ThinkCenter machines at the office, the screen brightness on the desktop displays is being set to the lowest setting. Using the monitor HUD the brightness can be changed again, but doing this several times a day is rather frustrating.

I get the impression some Lenovo software must be causing this, but haven't found anything. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I found [a description of the problem on Lenovo's support site](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=SF10-D0078), but it appears to be only applicable to Windows XP. On my Windows 7 machine, I'm running Power Manager 1.05.0008, which seems to be a newer version than the Windows 7 version available from Lenovo.

Answer (score 2):

After much digging around, I think I may have found the culprit. Since the brightness change is random, I can't say for certain it's resolved, but here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. Open Windows Power Options and open Lenovo's Power Manager from the sidebar on the left. (You can also locate this application by typing "Power Manager" in Start Search.)
   [image: Windows Power Manager]
2. In the Lenovo Power Manager, switch to "Advanced" mode.
   [image: Lenovo Power Manager]
3. Under the active power profile, ensure that the "monitor brightness" setting is set to the desired level.
   [image: Monitor brightness setting]
4. Under the "Global Power Settings" tab, make sure all "Dynamic Brightness Control" options are disabled.
   [image: Global Power Settings, Dynamic Brightness Control]
5. Under the "Options" tab, make sure "Magic Brightness Control" is disabled.
   [image: Options, Magic Brightness Control]
6. Press OK and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

I found a more recent version of Lenovo's Power Manager. There are versions for various flavors of Windows available from their support site:

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=migr-61432#power

Answer (score 0):

Just thought i would add my thoughts as this has been getting on my nerves for a while. In Windows what seemed to help me was changing the dam Adaptive Brightness setting to OFF this has caused me so many issues on many machines:

[image: adaptive]

I would of liked to add this as a comment because i still seem to have this issue booting into BIOS and Linux, but there did not seem to be an option for an image and i thought it may be helpful as it's quite a hidden setting.